# CSS strange behavior: suddenly borders around things

Tags: css

Take a look at this picture: [image: from jsfiddle] it is a zoomed screenshot from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/QPGfH/).So, what is the purple border around red bar?o_O It looks bad, and furthermore, thereafter in real application I get it in even more strange way: [image] - somewhere it exists but somewhere dont.

Better pics: [image: 1] [image: 2]

Comment: I don't see it, sorry. Even when I go into your fiddle and remove or change the background property in the `.finam{}` style I see no border around the red little box. I'm using Chrome if that makes a difference. What browser are you using?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Chrome 19.0.1084.46, one moment, I'll do better pics

Comment: Looks like an artifact of the `transform` style. It makes the edge of the element a bit transparent and blends it with the blue background.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl check my post now please:)

Comment: As @PeeHaa says, this is a transform artifact. It happens if you rotate around a point that is not exactly on a full pixel, so your transformed element ends up occupying half pixels on screen which the transform tries to mitigate with subpixel blending.

Comment: @scythargon: Thanks for the pics but I don't see it in the fiddle you linked. Sounds like `PeeHaa` and `Torsten` are on to something. May the effect is even influenced by the type of monitor and GPU you got. Not sure myself now.

Comment: @TorstenWalter thanks... will try to make areas [2*n+1]x[2*n+1] sizes

Comment: @TorstenWalter well, almost)) there are should be some more hard math:)))

Comment: @scythargon The size of your objects isn't that important. The rotational center is. You sure can have percentages and other float value lengths as `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we solved this problem on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183018/pixel-rectangle-precise-rotating), as a shortcut - *width and height should both be of the same parity (i.e. either both odd or both even)* (thanks Steven Stadnicki).